# How to display a PDF document in Delphi using TMS WEB Core?

Tags: delphi, pdf, tms, tms-web-core

I have a basic TMS WEB Core page with a panel and I want to display a PDF file within that panel.

I looked for PDF-related TMS components that can help me to show a PDF on a TMS WEB Core page, but couldn't really find anything super useful.

How can I display my PDF file on that panel?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out that showing PDFs in TMS WEB Core is actually super simple.

You can just drop a `TWebBrowserControl` component onto the form and set the `URL` property to the location of your PDF.

You can also do it via code:

```
WebBrowserControl.URL := 'Link_To_Your_PDF_File.pdf';
```

That will then show a PDF when running the website.

Comment: Does this work on all browsers? Also what happens if you disable showing of PDF-s in the browser like [Disable chrome PDF viewer](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/3308242/disable-chrome-pdf-viewer?hl=en) or [How do I stop Edge from opening PDF files?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/how-do-i-stop-edge-from-opening-pdf-files/ad12f630-5a6c-4139-8d77-f289014294fe). I have a feeling this solution might be heavily browser dependent.

Comment: I was right this is dependent on browser support for showing PDF's directly as can be seen in [Show a PDF from a TMS WEB Core app](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/blog.asp?post=726) blog post.

Comment: Of course it is. Better not encounter a browser which is not bloated by PDF support.